# Query from today to last month of today

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For example : today is 4 april 2015 
what I want to do is to select all record between current date to the last month of current date.

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date should be an actual MySQL column

This will get the last month:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY something DESC;`

Comment: Glad it worked @ChhornSoro :D ! Should probably check it so the question status is changed to "answered"

Comment: I have to wait 3 minute

Answer (score 1):

You most likely meant `last day of the current month` as indicated in the comments. If that is true, then in your where clause you would use:

```
where date_field between current_date and last_day(current_date)
```